# How to declare and use a list of string array?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I need to read a line in a file.
Based on the first 3 characters in the file, I can determine a type of record.

This indicates the number of strings the line needs to be split into.

I need to hold all lines of the same type in a List.

How do I do this?

My sample file would look like

> 123|gf|hf|gr|9
>
> 145*gf*43*434*9*645*554
>
> 123|grf|fe|yr|9

So all 123 would be in a list of string array type of length 4 like :

```
public List<string[]> NTE =new List<string[4]>();
```

Except declaring a length isn't being accepted by the compiler

Comment: `public List<string[]> NTE =new List<string[]>();` will do, and then per list element you could initialize with `new string[4]`

Comment: I suggest create a class and make 4 properties one for each string.

Comment: If you're asking a question about C# code then please don't use the VB.NET tag.  I have removed it.

Comment: What do you want to do if one particular line has too many values?  Do you want to abort the whole thing?  Ignore that line? Notify the user and continue?

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
List<string[]> NTE =new List<string[]>();
```

And then as you need to add an element to the `NTE`, you only need to specify that the size will be `4`:

```
NTE.Add(new string[4]); //here it is defined having size of 4, not in the list declaration
```

Then when you use it:

```
NTE[0] = ...something
```

That is going to be a `string[4]` array

Comment: I get I can set values of array[4] , but is there no way of initializing the size before hand? I'd like it to error out if the string has more than 4 values while assigning as part of my validation.

Comment: You could do something like: `List<string[]> NTE = new List<string[]>() { new string[4], new string[4], new string[4], new string[4] };` - but you essentially has to declare *each* individual `string[]` size. If your `string[]` has to be of size 4 on design time, then I recommend to wrap it in a class with property of `string[4]` and then you make list of that `class`: `List<MyClass>`

Comment: The `List` only knows or cares about the type of its items.  `string[]` is a type; `string[4]` is not.  If you want to validate then validate.  Don't expect the `List` to do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ArrayofFour
{
    string[] a = new string[4];

    public string this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            return a[i];
        }
        set
        {
            a[i] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Use the ArrayofFour instead of an array, you can use it like an array using the indexers. This will take care of validation you need.

Then you can have a `List<ArrayofFour> NTE = new List<ArrayofFour>();`

I think this is what you need or at least help you get there.